# imshow() function is not giving output as expected in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

```
import cv2
img=cv2.imread('test.jpg')
cv2.imshow("frame1",img)
waitKey(0)
```

[input_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/std3G.jpg)
[output_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UEvg.png)

Above is my code and it is not giving expected result(complete image). Roughly 10% of image is getting as output.
My input image is of size 1.24MB.is there any size limitations in opencv??

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: What do you mean by *Roughly 10% of image is getting as output*? Is the image only rendered partially? Could you share a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is arising from `cv2.imshow()` function. As you are using cv2 from python, the command to use would be `cv2.namedWindow('image',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)` before `cv2.imshow()`. This should solve your problem. I tried your code the following way and it worked for me.

```
import cv2
img=cv2.imread('input1.jpg')
cv2.namedWindow('image',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
#cv2.resizeWindow('image', 600,600)
cv2.imshow("image",img)
k = cv2.waitKey(0)
if k == 27:
    cv2.imwrite('newImage2.png', img)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

See if this can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the namedwindow() method to adjust the screen size to fit the image size.
Here is the function;

cv.NamedWindow(name, flags=CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)